# Pin group isomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, exact-sequence, spin-geometry

My goal is to identify the $Pin$ group 
$$
1 \to Spin(n) \to  Pin^{\pm}(n) \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1
$$
such that $Pin^{\pm}(n)$ are isomorphisms to other more familiar groups.

My trick is that to look at [the center $Z$ of $Pin$ group, say $Z(Pin(n))$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_group#Center).

We see that, for $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,

when $n=4k+1$,
$$
Z(Pin^+(4k+1))=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2,
$$
$$
Z(Pin^-(4k+1))=\mathbb{Z}_4.
$$

when $n=4k+3$,
$$
Z(Pin^+(4k+3))=\mathbb{Z}_4,
$$
$$
Z(Pin^-(4k+3))=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2.
$$

when $n=4k$ or when $n=4k+2$,
$$
Z(Pin^+(n))=Z(Pin^-(n))=\mathbb{Z}_2.
$$

> So my naive attempt is that we have the following $Pin$ group isomorphisms:
>
> $$Pin^+(1)=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2, \quad Pin^-(1)=\mathbb{Z}_4.$$
>
> $$Pin^+(3)=SO(3)  \times \mathbb{Z}_ 4, \quad Pin^-(3)=Spin(3) \times \mathbb{Z}_2.$$
>
> $$Pin^+(5)=Spin(5) \times \mathbb{Z}_2,\quad Pin^-(5)=SO(5) \times \mathbb{Z}_4.$$
>
> $$Pin^+(4k+1)=Spin(4k+1) \times \mathbb{Z}_2,\quad Pin^-(4k+1)=SO(4k+1) \times \mathbb{Z}_4.$$
>
> $$Pin^+(4k+3)=SO(4k+3)  \times \mathbb{Z}_ 4, \quad Pin^-(4k+3)=Spin(4k+3) \times \mathbb{Z}_2.$$
>
> **Question 1**: Am I correct about the above statements? I am not so sure, 
>   $Pin^+(3)=SO(3)  \times \mathbb{Z}_ 4$, could it be that instead
>   $Pin^+(3)=\frac{Spin(3)  \times \mathbb{Z}_4}{\mathbb{Z}_2}?$
>   (It looks that mine agrees with [Wikipedia, but I doubt Wikipedia may be wrong about $Pin^+(3)=SO(3)  \times \mathbb{Z}_ 4$...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_group#Low_dimensions))
>
> **Question 2**: Are there other $Pin$ group isomorphisms for $n=4k$, or $4k+2$, say $$Pin^{+/-}(4k)\simeq ?$$ and 
>   $$Pin^{+/-}(4k+2)\simeq?$$

Thanks for your comments in advance.